# Qual expressão regex nesse caso?

Tags: string, regex, formatação

Tenho essa string abaixo que preciso remover os \n do início e do final, sem remover entre as palavras.
Pensei em duas possibilidades porém não consegui montar a expressão.

1. De selecionar os \n do inicio e final e deletar.
2. De selecionar os \n iniciais até encontrar a primeira palavra com mais de 3 letras...

`\n \n  \n   \n  \n  \n   \n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n   \n  \n  \n   \n  \n \n`

Comment: Qual a linguagem de programação?

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem, nem precisa de regex - muitas possuem funções similares a  `trim`/`strip` que já remove caracteres do início e do final. De qualquer forma, se for mesmo usar regex, sugiro [edit] e colocar a linguagem e/ou ferramenta que está usando, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que serve pra uma pode não servir pra outra. Também não ficou claro se é uma sequência de `\n` ou se tem espaço entre eles (no exemplo que vc colocou tem espaços, mas na string tem?)

Answer (score -2):

pelo que entendi seria isso em js com a regex -> /\B\n+/g/

```js
let texto = "\n \n  \n   \n  \n  \n   \n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n    ultimo atend campo 6087\n   \n  \n  \n   \n  \n \n"

console.log(texto.replaceAll(/\B\n+/g,""))
```